# Pre-compiled Handlebars templates in Java Environment

Tags: java, javascript, ember.js, handlebars.js

I am creating an application with Ember, I would ask, how do I create the files `.hbs` to be put into folders and then call them up and use them as a template with Ember? I realized that I have to create the file pre-compiled with Handlebars but how do I give it a name, and printing them in view? Thank you very much, sorry for the "simple" question but I can not understand!

Comment: What technology are you using server-side?

Comment: i'm using java with Tomcat...

Comment: @sir_campy technically, you can call Myslik's [Ember-Handlebars compiler library](https://github.com/Myslik/csharp-ember-handlebars) (which is in .NET) [from Java](http://codefry.blogspot.ca/2012/01/calling-net-dlls-from-java-code-without.html). As for naming, you'll have to write a class to do what the [`IBundleTransform`](https://github.com/Myslik/csharp-ember-handlebars/blob/master/Ember.Handlebars/EmberHandlebarsBundleTransform.cs) implementation does, so your can name the templates correctly. Or you could implement something similar for Java environment.

Answer (score 3):

You need to have a server-side build process which will assemble your handlebars templates together. You can optionally compile them so that then you only need the handlebars runtime js library.

You could try this: http://blog.selvakn.in/2012/05/precompiling-handlerbars-tempates-with.html